# Kernel 4.12, virtualbox VM not working

Tags: upgrade, kernel, virtualbox

I get the error

> Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)

and that I should run as root `modprobe vboxdrv`.

Tried to do it and it didn't work. (says that the module dues not exists.) As mentioned over the web I've tried also:

```
apt-get update
sudo apt install --reinstall virtualbox-dkms
```

That also did not work:

```
------------------------------
Deleting module version: 5.1.6
completely from the DKMS tree.
------------------------------
Done.
Unpacking virtualbox-dkms (5.1.6-dfsg-2) over (5.1.6-dfsg-2) ...
Setting up virtualbox-dkms (5.1.6-dfsg-2) ...
Building only for 4.12.0-041200-generic
Building initial module for 4.12.0-041200-generic
ERROR (dkms apport): kernel package linux-headers-4.12.0-041200-generic is not supported
Error! Bad return status for module build on kernel: 4.12.0-041200-generic (x86_64)
Consult /var/lib/dkms/virtualbox/5.1.6/build/make.log for more information.
```

Comment: I think you have to go back to the old kernel... it's a clear message....
Sorry... I didn't show the message about Kernel driver

Comment: 4.8 is an "old" kernel. I was thinking that in a time period of a couple of months It should have being fixed. Are you sure there is no other way than going back to old kernel?

Comment: No... Ignore my message... I had not seen the problem about the kernel driver... Just read the message and thought it was clear you can't use the new kernel...

Comment: Check this https://forum.siduction.org/index.php?topic=6769.0... I don't know much about virtual box and can not expect that it works... But may be

Comment: Thanks, I'll check it this evening and update if it worked.

Comment: Please [file a bug report against the Virtual Box package](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/virtualbox) so that they may add support for this kernel to the package. Bug reports are off topic on Ask Ubuntu. In the mean time revert to a *supported* kernel version for your Ubuntu release.

Answer (score 4):

this worked on Ubuntu 16.04, x86_64 Kernel 4.12 (4.12.0-041200-generic)

- Change to the Virtualbox source directory

`cd /usr/share/virtualbox/src`

- get this patch and place it in /usr/share/virtualbox/src

`sudo wget http://paste.siduction.org/20170629003423`

- apply patch

`sudo patch -Np0 < 20170629003423`

- run vboxconfig by executing

`/sbin/vboxconfig`

have fun!

source: https://forum.siduction.org/index.php?topic=6769.0 plus my own experience

Comment: I only have:
"nls/"  "VBox.sh" &  "VBoxSysInfo.sh" inside /usr/share/virtualbox

Comment: Nice answer saved me!

Comment: If the src directory doesn't exist, uninstall virtualbox and install the latest package from virtualbox.org then apply the patch and run sudo /sbin/vboxconfig

Answer (score -1):

On the [page](https://forum.siduction.org/index.php?topic=6769.0) linked by @koleygr, the [patch](http://paste.siduction.org/20170629003423) linked by melmarker seems to work.  I'm able to compile on Gentoo Linux running 4.12, though I'm not sure about Ubuntu.

Patch:

```
diff -ruN vboxhost.orig/vboxdrv/linux/SUPDrv-linux.c vboxhost/vboxdrv/linux/SUPDrv-linux.c
--- vboxhost.orig/vboxdrv/linux/SUPDrv-linux.c  2016-08-22 00:00:00.000000000 +0200
+++ vboxhost/vboxdrv/linux/SUPDrv-linux.c   2017-05-31 19:00:22.887324690 +0200
@@ -1397,7 +1397,7 @@
 SUPR0DECL(uint32_t) SUPR0GetKernelFeatures(void)
 {
     uint32_t fFlags = 0;
-#ifdef CONFIG_PAX_KERNEXEC
+#if defined(CONFIG_PAX_KERNEXEC) || LINUX_VERSION_CODE >= KERNEL_VERSION(4, 12, 0)
     fFlags |= SUPKERNELFEATURES_GDT_READ_ONLY;
 #endif
 #if defined(VBOX_STRICT) || defined(VBOX_WITH_EFLAGS_AC_SET_IN_VBOXDRV)
diff -ruN vboxhost.orig/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/alloc-r0drv-linux.c vboxhost/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/alloc-r0drv-linux.c
--- vboxhost.orig/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/alloc-r0drv-linux.c   2016-08-22 00:00:00.000000000 +0200
+++ vboxhost/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/alloc-r0drv-linux.c    2017-05-31 19:03:32.465413475 +0200
@@ -35,7 +35,10 @@
 #include <iprt/assert.h>
 #include <iprt/err.h>
 #include "r0drv/alloc-r0drv.h"
-
+#include <linux/kmemleak.h>
+#if LINUX_VERSION_CODE >= KERNEL_VERSION(4, 12, 0)
+#include <asm/set_memory.h>
+#endif

 #if (defined(RT_ARCH_AMD64) || defined(DOXYGEN_RUNNING)) && !defined(RTMEMALLOC_EXEC_HEAP)
 # if LINUX_VERSION_CODE >= KERNEL_VERSION(2, 6, 23)
diff -ruN vboxhost.orig/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/memobj-r0drv-linux.c vboxhost/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/memobj-r0drv-linux.c
--- vboxhost.orig/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/memobj-r0drv-linux.c  2017-02-02 16:54:00.000000000 +0100
+++ vboxhost/vboxdrv/r0drv/linux/memobj-r0drv-linux.c   2017-05-31 19:23:05.187059423 +0200
@@ -899,6 +899,9 @@
     unsigned long   pfn;
     struct page    *pPage;
     pte_t          *pEntry;
+#if LINUX_VERSION_CODE >= KERNEL_VERSION(4, 12, 0)
+    p4d_t           p4d;
+#endif
     union
     {
         pgd_t       Global;
@@ -917,9 +920,18 @@
     u.Global = *pgd_offset(current->active_mm, ulAddr);
     if (RT_UNLIKELY(pgd_none(u.Global)))
         return NULL;
+#if LINUX_VERSION_CODE >= KERNEL_VERSION(4, 12, 0)
+    p4d = *p4d_offset(&u.Global, ulAddr);
+    if (RT_UNLIKELY(p4d_none(p4d) || p4d_large(p4d) || !p4d_present(p4d)))
+        return NULL;
+#endif

 #if LINUX_VERSION_CODE >= KERNEL_VERSION(2, 6, 11)
+#if LINUX_VERSION_CODE >= KERNEL_VERSION(4, 12, 0)
+    u.Upper = *pud_offset(&p4d, ulAddr);
+#else
     u.Upper = *pud_offset(&u.Global, ulAddr);
+#endif
     if (RT_UNLIKELY(pud_none(u.Upper)))
         return NULL;
 # if LINUX_VERSION_CODE >= KERNEL_VERSION(2, 6, 25)
@@ -1463,13 +1475,23 @@
 {
     int rc = -ENOMEM;
     pgd_t *pgd;
+#if LINUX_VERSION_CODE >= KERNEL_VERSION(4, 12, 0)
+    p4d_t *p4d;
+#endif

     spin_lock(&mm->page_table_lock);

     pgd = pgd_offset(mm, ulAddr);
     if (!pgd_none(*pgd) && !pgd_bad(*pgd))
     {
+#if LINUX_VERSION_CODE >= KERNEL_VERSION(4, 12, 0)
+        p4d = p4d_offset(*pgd, ulAddr);
+        if (p4d_none(*p4d))
+            goto exit;
+        pmd_t *pmd = pmd_offset(p4d, ulAddr);
+#else
         pmd_t *pmd = pmd_offset(pgd, ulAddr);
+#endif
         if (!pmd_none(*pmd))
         {
             pte_t *ptep = pte_offset_map(pmd, ulAddr);
@@ -1487,6 +1509,9 @@
         }
     }

+#if LINUX_VERSION_CODE >= KERNEL_VERSION(4, 12, 0)
+exit:
+#endif
     spin_unlock(&mm->page_table_lock);
     return rc;
 }
```